# How to call $resource custom method in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

I have a factory:

**myService:**

```
'use strict';
app.factory('myService', ['$resource', 'ngAuthSettings', function ($resource, ngAuthSettings) {
  var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;

  return $resource(serviceBase + 'api/category/', {}, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    },
    getAllByCategory: {
      url: serviceBase + 'api/category/GetAllByCategory',
        method: 'GET', isArray: true
    }
  });
}]);
```

Then I have a controller:

**searchController:**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('searchController',
    ['ngAuthSettings', '$scope', 'myService', '$routeParams', '$location',
    function (ngAuthSettings, $scope, myService, $routeParams, $location) {

    function init() {
        var search = $location.search();
        var keywords = search.keywords;            

        var model = myService.getAllByCategory({ categoryId: 2, page: $routeParams.page });

        $scope.categoryAds = model.ads;
        $scope.bigTotalItems = model.totalCount;
        $scope.maxSize = ngAuthSettings.maxPagingSize;
    }
    init();
}]);
```

Why my `model.ads` is always undefined? Isn't this the right way to call `$resource` custom method in controller?

Comment: I think you are using the right way for calling custom resource. I am guessing the error lies in your API which returns that data. Check `Network` tab in your chrome. See what is returned by API

Comment: @tanmay I checked WebApi using fiddler, it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As response may take some time but you are adding assignment very immediatly hence it happening put it in promise/action after resource,

```
'use strict';
    app.controller('searchController', ['ngAuthSettings', '$scope', 'myService', '$routeParams', '$location',
        function (ngAuthSettings, $scope, myService, $routeParams, $location) {
            function init() {
                var search = $location.search();
                var keywords = search.keywords;            
                var model = myService.getAllByCategory({ categoryId: 2, page: $routeParams.page }, 
                    function() {
                        $scope.categoryAds = model.ads;
                        $scope.bigTotalItems = model.totalCount;
                        $scope.maxSize = ngAuthSettings.maxPagingSize;
                    }
                );

            }
            init();
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: That's interesting, but why myService.query() works fine without promise?